# how to retrieve quarter and year values to date

Tags: time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the table below:

| Period | County | Cost | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2019 | DE | 1.54 | Product1 |
| 01/11/2019 | US | 2.35 | Product1 |
| 01/11/2019 | DE | 4.21 | Product2 |
| 01/11/2019 | US | 0.87 | Product2 |
| 01/12/2019 | DE | 1.456 | Product1 |
| 01/01/2020 | DE | 5.3 | Product2 |
| 01/02/2020 | US | 9.76 | Product1 |
| 01/03/2020 | DE | 6.78 | Product1 |
| 01/03/2020 | US | 1.2 | Product2 |
| 01/03/2020 | DE | 3.964 | Product2 |
| 01/04/2020 | US | 2.58 | Product1 |
| 01/04/2020 | US | 2.8 | Product2 |
| 01/04/2020 | DE | 0.5 | Product1 |

Code to test:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE "TMP_TEST" (
        "Period"  DATE,
        "Country"     VARCHAR,
        "Cost"    FLOAT,
        "Product"    VARCHAR
    );
    
    INSERT INTO "TMP_TEST" 
    VALUES 
('01/11/2019','DE','1.54','Product1'),
('01/11/2019','US','2.35','Product1'),
('01/11/2019','DE','4.21','Product2'),
('01/11/2019','US','0.87','Product2'),
('01/12/2019','DE','1.456','Product1'),
('01/01/2020','DE','5.3','Product2'),
('01/02/2020','US','9.76','Product1'),
('01/03/2020','DE','6.78','Product1'),
('01/03/2020','US','1.2','Product2'),
('01/03/2020','DE','3.964 ','Product2'),
('01/04/2020','US','2.58','Product1'),
('01/04/2020','US','2.8','Product2'),
('01/04/2020','DE','0.5 ','Product1');

select * from TMP_TEST;

WITH TOTAL AS (
    SELECT
        "Period","Country","Cost","Product"
    FROM "TMP_TEST"
)
SELECT
    TOTAL.*,
    IFF(UPPER("Country") = 'DE', "Cost", 0) as "Cost DE",
    IFF(UPPER("Country") = 'US', "Cost", 0) as "Cost US",
    DATEADD(MONTH, -1, "Period") AS "Period M-1",
    LAG("Cost", 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY "Country", "Product" ORDER BY "Period") AS "Cost USD M1",
    LAG("Cost DE", 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY "Country", "Product" ORDER BY "Period") AS "Cost DE M1",
    LAG("Cost US", 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY "Country", "Product" ORDER BY "Period") AS "Cost US M1"
FROM TOTAL
```

Now i want the same results adding a column for the total cost by product for current quarter (imagine we are on period 01/02/2020, i want cumulative sum for the product Quarter to date (january & febuary included))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH TOTAL AS (
    SELECT
        "Period","Country","Cost","Product"
    FROM "TMP_TEST"
)
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('Q',"Period") AS "Quarter",  -- New Quarter Column added for Quarter
    TOTAL.*,
    IFF(UPPER("Country") = 'DE', "Cost", 0) as "Cost DE",
   IFF(UPPER("Country") = 'US', "Cost", 0) as "Cost US",
    DATEADD(MONTH, -1, "Period") AS "Period M-1",
   LAG("Cost", 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY "Country", "Product" ORDER BY "Period") AS "Cost USD M1",
   LAG("Cost DE", 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY "Country", "Product" ORDER BY "Period") AS "Cost DE M1",
   LAG("Cost US", 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY "Country", "Product" ORDER BY "Period") AS "Cost US M1",
   SUM("Cost") OVER (PARTITION BY "Country", "Product","Quarter" ORDER BY "Period") AS"Quarter Cost", -- New Column added For Aggregation By Quarter TO Date

   SUM("Cost DE") OVER (PARTITION BY "Country", "Product","Quarter" ORDER BY "Period") AS"Quarter Aggregation Cost DE" -- New Column added For Aggregation By Quarter TO Date
 
FROM TOTAL;
```